# express - how to add a generic runtime exceptions handler?

Tags: node.js, express, async-await

I'm using express with `async/await`. When an `async` function is rejected, exception is thrown.
However, the client will not get a response for his request, leaving him hanging in the air.

How should I add a **global exception handler** for unhandled runtime exceptions? On these cases, server should reply with `"Server Error"` status code `500`.

- I don't want to wrap all of my server side functions with `try` and `catch`
- I don't want to hint the next request handler there was an error (e.g. `next(err);`)
- I've read https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html, couldn't find something as simple as I describe (have I missed something?)

This is my example express app:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 8080;

async function validate() {
    let shouldFail = Math.random() >= 0.5;
    if (shouldFail) {
        throw new Error();
    }
}

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    await validate();
    res.json({"foo": "bar"});
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on port ${port}!`));
```

> Note - the http function will fail randomly. It's just for demo purposes.

Comment: use  https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-promise-router  in this case no need to  wrap the code inside try catch ,  it will be handled by `express-promise-router`

Comment: just  install  the package and include the following code `const router = require("express-promise-router")();`  which will  used instead of normal express router

Comment: Why don't you want to use `next`? It's the pattern recommended by the authors.

Comment: @NikKyriakides - using `next()` makes my code error-aware, I want simplicity. fire and forget, knowing that some part of the ecosystem will handle that

Comment: It sounds like you're setting yourself up for major issues down the road. I can't elaborate in a comment why what you're trying to do sounds unwise.

Comment: @NikKyriakides - let's chat - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187052/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-54287923

Comment: No, you cannot add a *global* exception handler, as it wouldn't know from which request the exception came.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported in `express` out of the box. **However**, can be achieved with a minimalistic wrapper function.

Define the following function somewhere common,

```
function unhandledExceptionsHandler(asyncFunction) {
    return async (req, res, next) => {
        try {
            await asyncFunction(req, res, next);
        }
        catch (e) {
            // TODO Log error internally
            res.status(500).send("Server Error");
        }
    }
}
```

Wrap your callback function,

```
app.get('/', unhandledExceptionsHandler(async (req, res) => {
    await validate();
    res.json({"foo": "bar"});
}));
```

Answer (score -2):

`express` has built in error handling mechanism. You can configure generic error handler by adding a interceptor.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 8080;

async function validate() {
    let shouldFail = Math.random() >= 0.5;
    if (shouldFail) {
        throw new Error();
    }
}

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    await validate();
    res.json({"foo": "bar"});
});

// This interceptor will be called with err object if any of the above code breaks
// This should always be a last interceptor
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.stack)
  res.status(500).send('Something broke!')
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on port ${port}!`));
```

You can read more about `express` error handling [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html).

Comment: This will not work if you don't catch the error and pass it to the error handling middleware with `next(err)`.